# Use map() to find a range of sample sizes using pw

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to use `map2` or `pmap` to return a range of sample sizes necessary to find effects of a range of sizes.

So, I define a vector of effect sizes and a matching vector of acceptable powers.

```
f<-seq(0.1, 0.6, 0.1)
p<-seq(0.7, 0.9, length.out=6)
```

I use `expand.grid()` to come up with a matrix of pairs.

```
out<-expand.grid(f, p)
```

Now, I'd like to feed this to `map2` or `pmap` ( I am not sure which) to return a vector of sample sizes.
But my current effort returns an empty list.

What am I missing?

```
library(pwr)
library(purrr)
map2(.x=out$f, .y=out$p, ~ pwr.anova.test(k=5, f=.x, power=.y))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `pmap_dbl`:

In your code `map2` is iterating over two vectors `out$f` and `out$p`, but it is not returning a named list or a vector that can be combined.

- We could use `pmap_dbl` from the `purrr` to get a vector of sample
  sizes using the `.default` argument set to 5 (because k=5)
- We use an anonymous function with `~` having two arguments `..1` and
  `..2` which are placeholders for the first and second argument of
  this function.
- `$n` is used to extract the sample size `n` from the output of the
  `pwr.anova.test()` function. The resulting `n` value is then passed to the `pmap_dbl` function for each iteration.

This will return a vector of sample sizes for each combination of effect size and power, with the default value of 5 being used in case of any errors.

```
library(pwr)
library(purrr)
pmap_dbl(out, ~ pwr.anova.test(k = 5, f = ..1, power = ..2)$n, .default = 5)
```

```
 [1] 194.600370  49.369740  22.484423  13.084963   8.744943   6.397528
 [7] 211.003706  53.470142  24.306075  14.108628   9.398865   6.850309
[13] 229.437469  58.078205  26.353394  15.259232  10.133978   7.359474
[19] 250.729687  63.400866  28.718269  16.588445  10.983451   7.948001
[25] 276.315019  69.796826  31.560185  18.185947  12.004511   8.655601
[31] 309.051431  77.980467  35.196566  20.230229  13.311453   9.561547
```

Comment: OK, that's great. Can you walk me through this? I guess I am matching arguments here by position, right? The argument `f` in the function becomes the first column in `out` and the argument power takes the second column.  What is `$n` and `.default=5` do?

Answer (score 0):

Your error was in failing to examine the `out` dataframe. `expand.grid` does not assume the names of its arguments are the column names, so the names of `out`'s columns were 'Var1' and 'Var2'

```
library(pwr)
library(purrr)

> str(out)
'data.frame':   36 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: num  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 ...
 $ Var2: num  0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7 0.74 0.74 0.74 0.74 ...
 - attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
  ..$ dim     : int [1:2] 6 6
  ..$ dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ Var1: chr [1:6] "Var1=0.1" "Var1=0.2" "Var1=0.3" "Var1=0.4" ...
  .. ..$ Var2: chr [1:6] "Var2=0.70" "Var2=0.74" "Var2=0.78" "Var2=0.82" ...

# This succeeds

res <- map2(.x=out$Var1, .y=out$Var2, ~ pwr.anova.test(k=5, f=.x, power=.y)$n)

# The pwr.anova.test()$n pulls the element for the necessary sample size
# If you wanted the resulting value to be a atomic vector you could use unlist
res <- unlist(res)

# Or you could succeed with this code to get the names as you expected. Your code would have gotten a list of 36 lists, each with 5 elements, since you did not extract the sample size.

out <- expand.grid(f=f, p=p) 

# Note that if you had added `$n` immediately after the closing paren of 
# the `pwr.anova.test` call, you would have gotten a list of values.
# `unlist()`- it would get you the vector you were hoping for.
```